# BlockCypher Bitcoin Создание транзакции в тестовой сети

Tags: c#, bitcoin, blockchain

Я использую BlockCypher API для создания транзакции в тестовой сети Bitcoin. Происходит это в [3 этапа](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions):

1.Отправка объекта частично заполненной транзакции:

```
{
   "inputs":[
      {
         "addresses":[
            "mpAR4FZPTwj8tDZKai5HTKRGsoP4CkWVGg"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "outputs":[
      {
         "value":500000,
         "addresses":[
            "n4VZdQwm57PoBuTEGYKtbrLxpo8MbY7V5K"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

2.Локальное подписание полученной транзакции (использую метод `Sign` [отсюда](https://github.com/bscheiman/BlockCypher/blob/d6eca38fe2342ef3311686f19180324b5c95bfb1/Blockcypher.cs)). Подписывается именно содержимое поля `tosign`, а так же добавляется публичный ключ для нашего адреса в `pubkeys`.

3.Отправка подписанной транзакции:

```
{
   "pubkeys":[
      "03f1b0e3232f041363f4c6d92087639e7f1663f5b2a987dc058389d4aac83fec3e"
   ],
   "signatures":[
      "3045022100edd5864db38723ed468b1d93217e126004321eda2a180b2a74eebacf0e52f4a002200138e211f470dbed7d297322d31d5c9a8199e131127f64152294706993441c3e"
   ],
   "tosign":[
      "5072a79a73664cb6809eb6e540eae0a3b0e8a2e2a216f79a9c8c1cf2e0679c44"
   ],
   "tx":{
      "addresses":[
         "mpAR4FZPTwj8tDZKai5HTKRGsoP4CkWVGg",
         "n4VZdQwm57PoBuTEGYKtbrLxpo8MbY7V5K"
      ],
      "block_height":-1,
      "confirmations":0,
      "confirmed":"0001-01-01T00:00:00",
      "double_spend":false,
      "fees":0,
      "hash":"f9695ab967a5338684435aa179a96d6930b7748cc2937895c52c6415b6407f28",
      "inputs":[
         {
            "addresses":[
               "mpAR4FZPTwj8tDZKai5HTKRGsoP4CkWVGg"
            ],
            "output_index":1,
            "output_value":100000,
            "prev_hash":"607ba65e4a168c673819fa21a089b082b75fd4e90a1a4a2ebf32dbee6b5aede9",
            "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash"
         }
      ],
      "lock_time":0,
      "outputs":[
         {
            "addresses":[
               "n4VZdQwm57PoBuTEGYKtbrLxpo8MbY7V5K"
            ],
            "script":"76a914fc078e674113834f297325987d10409af7ec80e688ac",
            "script_type":"pay-to-pubkey-hash",
            "value":500000
         }
      ],
      "preference":"low",
      "received":"2021-03-27T11:12:20.259055446Z",
      "relayed_by":"92.101.184.223",
      "total":500000,
      "ver":1,
      "vin_sz":1,
      "vout_sz":1
   }
}
```

На моменте отправки подписанной транзакции сервер возвращает ошибку:

> {"error": "Couldn't deserialize request: parsing time
> ""0001-01-01T00:00:00"" as ""2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"": cannot parse
> """ as "Z07:00""}

Средств на адресе хватает (0.001 BTC). Не могу понять с чем связана ошибка.

Comment: А вы читали текст ошибки? Понимаете что не нравится формат времени? Обращали внимание в примерах документации на большую букву Z в конце дат?

Comment: Есть такой пример: `2015-05-22T05:10:00.305308666Z`. Странность в том, что в таком формате дату возвращает сервер. Я лишь заполняю каркас объекта, остальные поля - сервер. Далее ни одно поле изменяться не должно.

Comment: Хотя вы правы. Ответ сервера я сначала десериализую, потом снова сериализую. И на этом моменте прокол. Как настроить JsonConverter правильно дату в строку конвертировать?

Comment: Для начала неплохо бы указать, что такое JsonConverter: это из [System.Text.Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1?view=netcore-3.1) или [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

Comment: Последнее. Разобрался уже. Только теперь появляется ошибка, связанная с подписанием транзакции. Не знаете как с помощью NBitcoin подписать приватным ключом транзакцию в hex-формате, которую отправляет сервер на локальное подписание?

Comment: Лично я никогда с биткойнами дела не имел и не планирую. А что по этому поводу сказано в документации? Может вам закрыть этот вопрос (хотите сами дать ответ?), поковыряться в документации и попробовать задать новый вопрос?

Comment: Ну в документации указано использовать их собственную утилиту, но она на языке GO. Мне то на C# нужно библиотеку. А ответ я дам, да)

Answer (score 0):

Проблема связана с тем, что `JsonConvert` сериализует дату в неподходящем формате. Нужно добавить:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = new Func<JsonSerializerSettings>(() => {
    return new JsonSerializerSettings() {
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc
    };
});
```